# Swapping <div> position causes loss of CSS3 transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I've got an issue which seems to be caused by altering the position of two `<divs>` within their parent, essentially re-ordering them.

Both divs have a `transition` css rule applied like so:

```
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

When I call this to swap the position:

```
function swapElements(first, second) {
    $(first).insertBefore(second);
}
```

The `first` element is not having the transition effect applied by the browser, it essentially doesn't animate at all after having been swapped with the previous/second element.

This is a problem as I'm listening to the transition end callback to then do some more work within the `<div>` (initializing a gallery):

```
if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
        $(roomColumn).one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function () {
           if (!gallery.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                $(gallery).slick({
                    lazyLoad: 'progressive',
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    autoplay: false,
                    dots: false,
                    adaptiveHeight: false
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Because the browser isn't doing the transition for this element, the event `.one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function (){});` is never fired for this `<div>` and so the gallery is not initialized for it.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this behaviour?

Edit: [Here is a very crude JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fno5bzx/). You will need to expand the output window so that are four columns.

As you can see, clicking any of the first three gives you an animation effect, clicking the last `<div>` in the row, labelled `LAST ROOM`, does not cause any animation to occur.

Interestingly, if I wrap the `<div>` swapping code in a `setTimeout` call it works fine, it seems like a timing issue, obviously I don't want to rely on this as a hacky fix though, it also causes the div to jump into place which is undesirable.

Comment: @Harry I'll give it a go, sure

Comment: @Harry Added a js fiddle. Expand the output window so that you get four columns, click any of the first three, you will get the animation, clicking the last div which triggers the swap causes no animation to occur.

Comment: I think I know why. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2fno5bzx/1/) what you need?

Comment: @Harry, yes that works perfectly, can you explain why though? The timeout doesn't even have a duration! I've got it to work using a similar approach but using a delay equal to the CSS transition e.g .2 seconds

Comment: This does have the unwanted side effect of not initializing the gallery correctly though, for some reason, the slider arrows don't function, clicking them re-runs the `<div>` animation again

Comment: @Harry Thank you, I'm using slick slider, I can update the fiddle to include the relevant code if necessary

Comment: I managed to fix this issue by binding to the gallery arrows inside the  `$('.js-hook--room-expand')` event and calling `e.stopPropagation();`, it seems the arrow click event was bubbling all the way up to the parent pod and re-triggering the animation

Comment: You mean the whole one or just that part?

Comment: Just the issue with the gallery, it seems it was initialised fine, it was just the gallery navigation click events were bubbling up to the parent pod, causing the animation to fire off again. The issue with the animation effect was solved by the `window.setTimeout` trick :)

Comment: And the animation re-run issue still exists right?

Comment: @Harry No the animation re-run issue was caused by the gallery arrows click event bubbling up to the parent pod, clicking the parent pod is what causes the animation to run, so it was bubbling up and re-running it. The `window.setTimeout` was the key fix here though, can you add it as an answer and explain why it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens because after swapping, you are also removing the original classes (for the small box display) and replacing with the new ones (for the larger display). All three happen within a single blocking call. Whenever an element is added, the browser would need to trigger a reflow but it doesn't trigger the reflow after each step as doing so will affect performance. So, the reflow happens at the end (after execution of the removeClass and addClass also) and thus there is only an element with new classes which is being painted on the screen - no state change and so no transition also.

To overcome this, we ***need to force the UA to trigger a reflow/repaint after swapping but before the class changes***. This can be done in ***two ways*** - one is to force the class change statements into a different function call (anonymous function using `setTimeout`) and the  other is by forcing the UA to calculate things like `clientHeight` etc (they force a repaint because they can only then calculate the actual height).

[Demo with setTimeout](https://jsfiddle.net/2fno5bzx/1/) | [Demo with clientHeight](https://jsfiddle.net/2fno5bzx/2/)

Comment: Thanks, perfect explanation.